# Dynamic font embedding and formatting textflow with them

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tlf, textflow

I am loading multiple swf files containing the different fonts at run-time. I am having problem when I am applying it to textflow in Rich Editable Text. Any Idea how to apply those custom fonts to the textflow ?

Here is the part of my code.

#### For registering the fonts

```
var FontClass:*;
var dom:ApplicationDomain = response.target.applicationDomain; 
FontClass = dom.getDefinition(fileName) as Class;
Font.registerFont(FontClass);
```

Works!

#### For applying the font to textflow.

```
 var cf:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
    cf.fontFamily = mFontName; //Font Name
    cf.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF; 

    var editManager: IEditManager = IEditManager(textflow.interactionManager);
    editManager.applyLeafFormat(cf);
```

No crash! Works!

But the applied font is not correct. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

`IEditManager` is an interface, it doesn't do anything. You should be using [`EditManager`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/edit/EditManager.html).

Interfaces are not working classes, they used to define a common set of functions, any class that implements an interface, has to create working versions of all functions defined in the interface, or the compiler will fail. Further reading [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf688f1-7ff1.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering it but It didn't work.The problem is with applying custom fonts to TextFlow. If I am applying the device font (e.g. Segoe) with the same code, it works correctly. I have user defined set of Fonts and I have embedded them to different swf's. I am able to load and embed the swf into my application but they are not applying to the textflow. For example I have a font clearviewATT, I have different swf files for its different styles (e.g.bold,regular,bolditalic,light etc)when I am applying the font to the textflow, it seems that the text is formatted to the default font family.

Comment: Add this detail to your question, all information is helpful